# Solve for unknown in an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please bear with me as I am very confident on how to solve for an unknown in an equation but this is what my teacher posted as an answer which I cannot get.

The question is to find `s / root (n)` in the following equation:

$26.5 + 1.753\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}=0$

and somehow the teacher got `2.2818` for the $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$

Assuming we replace numbers with `x` and `y` and `z`, then the above should be as follow:

```
x + y (z) = 0
y(z) = - x
z = -x / y
```

which does not give `2.2818` it gives `-15.116`

can someone please confirm my answer before I contact the teacher about this mistake?

P.S : I know this is a simple question, I just want to make sure this is a mistake from teacher when writing notes

Comment: You are correct. I edited your question to make it more readable.

Comment: You are perfectly correct.